# Verify user password in Firebase Auth before deleting account

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase Auth for user verification and would like to verify a users password before they delete or disable their account. How can this be performed?

I have tried the code below, but It does not seem to work.

```
  unregisterUser = (payload) => {
    console.log('unregisterUser payload', payload)
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
    .then( (user) => {
      //Success
      console.log('signInWithEmailAndPassword ok', user)
      console.log('signIn success')
      return Promise.resolve(true)
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
      //Fail
      console.error('signInWithEmailAndPassword error', error.code, error.message)
      console.error('error', error)
      return Promise.reject(error)
    })
 })
```

The only console logout I get is

```
unregisterUser payload Object { uid: "ABCDEFG12345", password: "111" }
```

I have read [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth) but cannot seem to find any other way to check a users password.

[The documentation states](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#delete) that I should first authenticate again and then call `firebase.User.reauthenticateWithCredential` before `firebase.User.delete`.

How can this be done?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the correct way to do it!

```
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(payload.email, payload.password)
    user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log('result', result)
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('error', error)
      console.log('code', error.code)
      // ...
    })
```

/K